# remove DOM tags from a JSON request

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode

I'm building a web service for my iOS phone application, and I'm having some trouble with JSON requests.

I figured out that my JSON PHP page is actually returning DOM element tags to the JSON Serialization.

Example JSON:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
{
    "results": [
        {
            "user": {
                "firstname": "jerry",
                "lastname": "barman",
                "username": "yellowbear927",
                "street": "2507 valley view ln",
                "thumbnail": "https:\/\/randomuser.me\/api\/portraits\/thumb\/women\/84.jpg",
                "rate": "9.00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what the iOS application is reading, and it causes an error.  If I remove the DOM elements from the PHP page, no errors and the code works fine, but my JSON looks like crap if I need to debug it from inside a browser.

Anyway I can get the best of both worlds?

Here is my example PHP:

```
$dataMult = array(
    "results" => array(
        array(
            "user" => array(
                "firstname" => "jerry",
                "lastname" => "barman",
                "username" => "yellowbear927",
                "street" => "2507 valley view ln",
                "thumbnail" => "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/84.jpg",
                "rate" => "9.00"
            )
        )
    )
);



?>

<html>
<body>
    <pre>
    <?php echo json_encode($dataMult, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);?>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my Swift Code:

```
func getHTTPRequest(urlPath: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        do {
            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            let json = JSON(jsonResult)
            onCompletion(json, error)
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            NSLog("%@", dataString!)
        } catch let error as NSError{
            print("Something went wrong.")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print(error.description)
            NSLog("%@", error)
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            NSLog("%@", dataString!)
        }

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Surely when you're debugging from the browser you can just view the page source of the JSON without the HTML elements?

Comment: Of course, but all the code is on a single line and very difficult to read without being inside of <pre> tags.

Comment: `<pre>` just lays out response in the same format as the source (and therefore prevents formatting from the browser). I'm suggesting that when you see the single line of JSON, you go to _View -> Developer -> View Source_ in your browser to see the raw output (AKA the same format `<pre>` would present you)

Comment: That's just another unneeded step I don't wish to take, and doesn't fix what I am trying to accomplish. I KNOW it's possible to have DOM elements and still work, checkout http://api.randomuser.me/ ... thier code is both formatted and works in the Apps JSON requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to create arbitrary DOM elements in a JSON document. Doing so would cause the JSON to be invalid.

The link you provided in the comments (api.randomuser.me) *does not* define any DOM elements itself - but instead sends an HTTP `Content-Type` header to instruct the browser that the content is JSON, *not* HTML. The browser is then smart enough to format it nicely for output, adding some basic DOM elements and placing the JSON in a `<pre>` for you.

You can invoke this behavior by overriding the default HTTP `Content-Type` by adding `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$dataMult = array(
    "results" => array(
        array(
            "user" => array(
                "firstname" => "jerry",
                "lastname" => "barman",
                "username" => "yellowbear927",
                "street" => "2507 valley view ln",
                "thumbnail" => "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/84.jpg",
                "rate" => "9.00"
            )
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($dataMult, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);?>
```

More information on the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this.  Thank you!